# Reading xml document into XmlDocument object

Tags: xml, vb.net, web-services

I have published xml document through web service like this

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Function HelloWorld() As XmlDocument
    Dim xmlDoc As New XmlDocument
    xmlDoc.Load(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory & "\Product.xml")
    Return xmlDoc
End Function
```

How do i read this Xml document into xmldocument object from other web service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use the XmlDocument as the return type at all.  I would suggest simply returning the XML as a string, for instance:

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Function HelloWorld() As String
    Return File.ReadAllText(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory & "\Product.xml")
End Function
```

Then, in your client application, you can load the XML string into the XmlDocument object:

```
Dim xmlDoc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()
xmlDoc.LoadXml(serviceRef.HelloWorld())
```

But, if you need to keep the method returning an XmlDocument, keep in mind that it is a complex type, so on the client side, it will be represented as a proxy type, not the actual XmlDocument type.  So, you would need to create a new XmlDocument and load it from the xml text from the proxy:

```
Dim xmlDoc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()
xmlDoc.LoadXml(serviceRef.HelloWorld().InnerXml)
```